# Emails - Tables sitting side by side

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-table, html-email

I am trying to get two tables to sit side by side in an email (basically floating against each other) so that when the container is reduced in size the one on the left will drop underneath the other? At the minute i have the two tables, with `float:left` on each table. I have tried adding display:inline on both and that didn't work. They work perfectly in every email client apart from Outlook 2007. Does anyone know why this could be and if there is a workaround.

Comment: Please add some code here. We don't have crystal balls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `align="left"` for the first table here is an [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/33zGb/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, tried everything and this worked! It makes sense know, I know using float is dodgy in emails so it makes sense to apply the align to the table itself. Cheers!

Comment: Yes in email template always use attribute or inline style this is the way work all and well.. welcome